# Repeating a date in polars and exploding it

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars, rust-polars

I have a polars dataframe with two date columns that represent a start and end date and then a value that I want to repeat for all dates in between those two dates so that I can join those on other tables.

Example input is

| id | start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 | 10 |
| abc | 2022-03-04 | 2022-03-04 | 3 |
| 456 | 2022-05-11 | 2022-05-16 | 4 |

and expected output is

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-01-01 | 10 |
| 123 | 2022-01-02 | 10 |
| 123 | 2022-01-03 | 10 |
| 123 | 2022-01-04 | 10 |
| abc | 2022-03-04 | 3 |
| 456 | 2022-05-11 | 4 |
| 456 | 2022-05-12 | 4 |
| 456 | 2022-05-13 | 4 |
| 456 | 2022-05-14 | 4 |
| 456 | 2022-05-15 | 4 |
| 456 | 2022-05-16 | 4 |

Comment: What exactly is "a polars dataframe"?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled today with the same problem and I thought I share my solution.

As cbilot already mentions pl.dat_range doesn't take expressions as low and high value. So I worked around by using apply.

Data:

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["123", "abc", "456"],
        "start": [date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 11)],
        "end": [date(2022, 1, 4), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 16)],
        "value": [10, 3, 4],
    }
)
```

Solution:

```
(
    df.with_columns(
        [(pl.struct(["start", "end"])
            .apply(lambda x: pl.date_range(x["start"], x["end"], "1d"))
            .alias("date"))])
    .explode(pl.col("date"))
    .select(["id", "date", "value"])
)


shape: (11, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ date       ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ... ┆ ...        ┆ ...   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-14 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-15 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: What I really like about your solution is that it will work for durations other than 1 day.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, is super elegant and easily extensible. Was trying to do the `date_range` and `explode` but didn't figure out the struct.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to implement it without using apply:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{
    "id": ["123", "abc", "456"],
    "start": [date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 11)],
    "end": [date(2022, 1, 4), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 16)],
    "value": [10, 3, 4],
})

df = df.with_columns(
        [pl.date_range(low=pl.col('start'), high=pl.col('end'), interval='1d')
        .alias('date')])\
    .explode('date')\
    .select(["id", "date", "value"])
```

Comment: Nice answer!

To avoid a deprecation warning this should use [pl.date_ranges](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.date_ranges.html) these days.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this data:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["123", "abc", "456"],
        "start": [date(2022, 1, 1), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 11)],
        "end": [date(2022, 1, 4), date(2022, 3, 4), date(2022, 5, 16)],
        "value": [10, 3, 4],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ start      ┆ end        ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     │
└─────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

##### The Algorithm

```py
(
    df.with_columns(
        [pl.arange(pl.col("start"), pl.col("end") + 1).alias("date")])
    .explode("date")
    .with_column(pl.col("date").cast(pl.Date))
    .select(["id", "date", "value"])
)
```

```
shape: (11, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ date       ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-12 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-14 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-15 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘
```

##### In steps

Normally, we create a range of dates using the [`date_range`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.date_range.html) expression.  However, `date_range` does not take an Expression as its `low` and `high` parameters.

However, [`arange`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.arange.html) does allow Expressions as its `low` and `high` parameters.  We can (implicitly) cast the `start` and `end` dates to integers, which represent the number of days since the UNIX epoch.

The result is a list of integers which represents the days between (and including) the `start` and `end` dates (expressed as days since the UNIX epoch)..

Notice that we have to add 1 to the `high` parameter to make sure we capture the end date.

```py
(
    df.with_columns(
        [pl.arange(pl.col("start"), pl.col("end") + 1).alias("date")])
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ start      ┆ end        ┆ value ┆ date                      │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---                       │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64]                 │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    ┆ [18993, 18994, ... 18996] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     ┆ [19055]                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ [19123, 19124, ... 19128] │
└─────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

Next we can use [`explode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html) to place each of the integers on a separate row.

```py
(
    df.with_columns(
        [pl.arange(pl.col("start"), pl.col("end") + 1).alias("date")])
    .explode("date")
)
```

```
shape: (11, 5)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ start      ┆ end        ┆ value ┆ date  │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 18993 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 18994 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 18995 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    ┆ 18996 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     ┆ 19055 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 19123 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 19124 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 19125 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 19126 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 19127 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     ┆ 19128 │
└─────┴────────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

The final step is to cast the `date` column back to a `pl.Date`, and then select only the columns that we want.

```py
(
    df.with_columns(
        [pl.arange(pl.col("start"), pl.col("end") + 1).alias("date")])
    .explode("date")
    .with_column(pl.col("date").cast(pl.Date))
    .select(["id", "date", "value"])
)
```

```
shape: (11, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ date       ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-02 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-03 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 123 ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 10    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ abc ┆ 2022-03-04 ┆ 3     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-11 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-12 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-13 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-14 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-15 ┆ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 456 ┆ 2022-05-16 ┆ 4     │
└─────┴────────────┴───────┘
```